# perl printing range of numbers with a newline at the end

Tags: perl

I was trying to print 1 to 10 using perl.

```
print 1..10 #This works perfectly fine.
```

I am wondering if there is a way to add a new line after printing the last element.

```
print "1..10" . "\n" ; # it just  prints 1..10 (as expected) instead of 12345678910

print "{1..10} . "\n" ; # This doesn't work either :(
```

I know I could just store it in a list and then print the list :

```
my @test = 1..10 ;

print @test ;
```

I am just wondering if there is a trick with print to do it in 1 line. 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: `print join "\n", 1..10`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass the 10 numbers and a newline to `print` (which will print each in turn), you can use the following:

```
print 1..10, "\n";
```

---

If instead you want to build a string that consists of the numbers followed by a newline, you can use either of the following:

```
print join("", 1..10, "\n");
```

```
print join("", 1..10) . "\n";
```

---

Test:

```
$ perl -e'
   print 1..10, "\n";
   print join("", 1..10, "\n");
   print join("", 1..10) . "\n";
   print "done.\n";
'
12345678910
12345678910
12345678910
done.
```

Comment: AWESOME !! exactly what I wanted to know !! Thanks :)